# TDD: best practices mocking stacks of objects

Tags: php, architecture, phpunit, tdd, lumen

I'm trying to get familiar with unit testing in PHP with a small API in Lumen.
Writing the first few tests was pretty nice with the help of some tutorials but now I encountered a point where I have to mock/ stub a dependency.

My controller depends on a specific custom interface type hinted in the constructor.
Of course, I defined this interface/implementation-binding within a ServiceProvider.

```php
    public function __construct(CustomValidatorContract $validator)
    {
        // App\Contracts\CustomValidatorContract
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function resize(Request $request)
    {
        // Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
        $validation = $this->validator->validate($request->all());

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            $response = array_merge(
                $validation
                ->errors() // Illuminate\Support\MessageBag
                ->toArray(), 
                ['error' => 'Invalid request data.']
            );

            // response is global helper
            return response()->json($response, 400, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, my `CustomValidatorContract` has a method `validate()` which returns an instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` (the validation result). This in turn returns an instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` when `errors()` is called. `MessageBag` then has a `toArray()`-method.

Now I want to test the behavior of my controller in case the validation fails.

```php
    /** @test */
    public function failing_validation_returns_400()
    {
        $EmptyErrorMessageBag = $this->createMock(MessageBag::class);
        $EmptyErrorMessageBag
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('toArray')
            ->willReturn(array());

        /** @var ValidationResult&\PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject $AlwaysFailsTrueValidationResult */
        $AlwaysFailsTrueValidationResult = $this->createStub(ValidationResult::class);
        $AlwaysFailsTrueValidationResult
            ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
            ->method('fails')
            ->willReturn(true);
        $AlwaysFailsTrueValidationResult
            ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
            ->method('errors')
            ->willReturn($EmptyErrorMessageBag);

        /** @var Validator&\PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject $CustomValidatorAlwaysFailsTrue */
        $CustomValidatorAlwaysFailsTrue = $this->createStub(Validator::class);
        $CustomValidatorAlwaysFailsTrue
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('validate')
            ->willReturn($AlwaysFailsTrueValidationResult);

        $controller = new ImageResizeController($CustomValidatorAlwaysFailsTrue);
        $response = $controller->resize(new Request);

        $this->assertEquals(400, $response->status());
        $this->assertEquals(
            'application/json',
            $response->headers->get('Content-Type')
        );
        $this->assertJson($response->getContent());
        $response = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('error', $response);
    }
```

This is a test that runs ok - but can someone please tell me if there is a better way to write this? It doesn't feel right. 
Is this big stack of moc-objects needed because of the fact that I'm using a framework in the background? Or is there something wrong with my architecture so that this feels so "overengineered"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not unit testing because you are not testing a single unit of your application. This is an integration test, performed with unit testing framework, and this is the reason it looks intuitively wrong.

Unit testing and [integration testing](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/integration-testing/) happen at different times, at different places and require different approaches and tools - the former tests every single class and function of your code, while latter couldn't care less about those, they just request APIs and validate responses. Also, IT doesn't imply mocking anything because it's goal is to test how well your units integrate with each other.

You'll have hard time supporting tests like that because every time you change `CustomValidatorContract` you'll have to fix all the tests involving it. This is how UT improves code design by requiring it to be as loosely coupled as possible (so you could pick a single unit and use it without the need to boot entire app), respecting [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) & [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), etc.

You don't need to test 3rd party code, pick an already tested one instead. You don't need to test side effects either, because environment is just like 3rd party service, it should be tested separately (`return response()` is a side effect). Also it seriously slows down the testing.

All that leads to the idea that you only want to test your `CustomValidatorContract` in isolation. You don't even need to mock anything there, just instantiate the validator, give it few sets of input data and check how it goes.

Comment: OK, I see your point. I already created unit tests for validation logic. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post this code as an answer.
Actually, I also put this test of the controller method into a separate directory called "feature" (seen in a tutorial) to separate it from (other) unit tests.
What I was trying to achieve was, to have a test that ensures that the if-statment is properly executed. Of course I will separate the building of the response into something else. But I will stay with the need to check, if a failed validation leads the controller onto a different path.

Comment: You're on the right track with testing the `if` - the rule of thumb, at least the one I use the most, is that number of test cases for a unit equals the number of execution path branches within that unit. So, if you are after covering your controller 100%, you'd need two test cases.

Comment: Thanks, really :)
Having those two tests wouldn't that lead me again to the point that I have to mock all the services and modules which will be called within the controller? Even if this wouldn't be called a "real" unit test it would be subject to the fact that I would have to mock many object in a complex structure. This eventually leads to a test wich will hardly depends on the way the mocking is done even if this mocking is just the configuration of the test.

Comment: Yes, it is inevitable, simple things gather together and make complex things, and there is a complexity threshold after which mocking all the dependencies becomes unreasonably tedious. This is when you take an "abstraction leap" and start treating complex thing as a single unit, and test it on a different level (for example, with an API testing tool). Along that way you learn how to keep deps reasonable, interfaces clear and learn about Occam's Razor — don't multiply entities you don't know how to test :)

Comment: My personal opinion on what to test is to isolate side effects from pure computations and logic, make the latter as procedural & idempotent as possible and UT them. Controllers (as well as API clients and platform API like POSIX) live in the grey area of side effects, so they are not tested as units; instead they act as an "environmental interface" for the BL code which is procedural & testable in complete isolation, including all kinds of validators, API clients, DB query generators and whatnot. The public API is then tested with an API testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a test that runs ok - but can someone please tell me if there is a better way to write this? It doesn't feel right. Is this big stack of moc-objects needed because of the fact that I'm using a framework in the background? Or is there something wrong with my architecture so that this feels so "overengineered"?

The big stack of mock objects indicates that your test subject is tightly coupled to many different things.

If you want to support simpler tests, then you need to make the design simpler.

In other words, instead of `Controller.resize` being one enormous monolithic thing that knows all of the details about everything, think about a design where resize only knows about the surface of things, and how to delegate work to other (more easily tested) pieces.

This is normal, in the sense that TDD is a lot about choosing designs that support better testing.

Comment: could you explain this a bit more? As this is the main reason for me to start with TDD I tried to achieve that. I already excluded the validation-logic and type hinted its interface within the constructor. Excluding everything else out of the controller will lead me to the point that it'll call everything in the right order and delegate values to the respective module. But then I will have to mock every module within the controller to test if the control logic around these modules behaves the right way. Shouldn't be, for example, the controller the only one returning responses